# JavaScript console errors in Google Search Console - is it still mobile-friendly?

Tags: google-search-console, javascript, mobile, crawl-errors, googlebot-mobile

I am seeing mobile usability issues in my Google Search Console report. When I tested the pages they were 'Mobile Friendly' but there were some page loading issues:

> page resources couldn’t be loaded [image]

and

> Java script console errors[image]

For the former one, some resources were blocked by my `robots.txt` file, and some others were for Google Analytics and ads. I did some research and found they are not relevant unless they are from my site.

I don't understand however if the JavaScript console errors are responsible for a page not being mobile-friendly or not as the test shows page is mobile-friendly.

Comment: More than likely it's still mobile-friendly, though the JavaScript errors might prevent the page from being displayed properly in some browsers, including mobile browsers. The first two errors suggest you likely didn't link JQuery correctly - either it's missing, or specified as a relative URL (or possibly just `http` instead of `https`). Try searching and replacing it with one of the absolute URLs from a JQuery CDN. For the first set of errors, unblock them in your _robots.txt_ directives if you want them to be displayed without errors in Google Search Console.